# Connect 30" Apple Cinema HD Display to 2018 Mac Mini

Tags: display, mac-mini, hdmi, displayport, cinema-display

I am trying to run an Apple Cinema HD Display (30") from a 2018 MacMini.

I have tried all kinds of HDMI- to DVI adaptors but so far no luck. I have also tried these connectors with a MacBook Pro with HDMI and although the computer recognises that there is a display attached (and gets the name of it etc) the display remains blank.

I've seen people doing this with USB-C, first converting to DisplayPort and then converting that to DualLink DVI... but I'm not sure if this same setup would work for HDMI, or what connectors are needed.

Maybe HDMI-DisplayPort then DisplayPort-DVI?

Comment: Try [this adapter](https://www.amazon.com/Mini-DisplayPort-Dual-Link-DVI-Adapter/dp/B0751RL35H) sold on Amazon. It is the official Apple adapter which is no longer sold in the Apple Store. When it comes to attaching quirky (and TBH, ancient) monitors to newer Macs, Apple had the adapters which work. Other Frankendongles cause only pain.

Comment: @IconDaemon thanks! And would you then add an HDMI-Mini DisplayPort dongle to run from the Mac Mini's HDMI port?

Comment: It _might_ work, but I wouldn't create a Frankendongle - they frequently just won't cut it. Use this device from a Thunderbolt port on the Mini directly to the Cinema Display. If you do use a MDP > HDMI, I'd use [this Belkin adaptor](https://www.amazon.com/Belkin-Mini-Displayport-Adapter-White/dp/B004RHNJOG) or this more sturdy [Belkin adaptor 4K](https://www.amazon.com/Belkin-DisplayPort-Adapter-Compatible-Black/dp/B013P0JTX0). The 4K adapter, while 3x more expensive, is much more rugged than the white adaptor.

Comment: @IconDaemon thanks for the advice above, it worked with the Apple adapter plus another dongle to go from Mini DisplayPort to USB-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re connecting a Mac mini 2018 to 30" Apple Cinema Display<sup>*</sup>:

<sup>* Apple Cinema Display 30" refers to TFT-LCD model (M9179LL/A) only! This does NOT work for the LED apple cinema displays.</sup>

You need the following:

1. Power Adapter of the Apple Cinema Display
2. The apple mini display port (mini DP) to Dual Link DVI adapter (sold second hand only, 30-150 USD) apple number MB571LL/A A1306
   and
3. USB-C to Mini Display Port adapter from LMP (https://lmp-adapter.com/?s=16138) (ca. 30 USD from new.)

This combination runs smoothly at 2560x1600